# PHP MySQL WHERE Clause with condition

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Table `video`

```
id | path
4  | 89_1232
6  | 90_2121
```

I need to match `path` before underscore `_`. For instance `89` , `90`. Is it possible with MySQL query.

Right now what I am doing is, fetching all rows and then explode `path` row:

```
"SELECT `path` FROM `video`
```

then `foreach () { explode and check }`

Comment: `path LIKE  "%' . $value . '_"`

Comment: I'm worried you have put two separate pieces of data in one column, consider separating these out into two columns, then you can index and match all the parts independently.. you can always concat on select if you need the original display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `LIKE` with wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Example:

```
SELECT `path` FROM `video` WHERE `path` LIKE '89\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

which will search for rows with the pattern `89_{anything}`, using the backslash `\` as the escape character (to make sure the underscore `_` is literal)

Comment: Actually underscore means one of any character unless escaped.

Comment: I'd also point out, that as this is the left most portion of the string, it can still use an index on the column.. which is why I'd use this method over SUBSTRING_INDEX.